# How can I output/manipulate the CSS filepath string in DevTools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, pretty-print

[image]

At the company I work for, we have a LOT of different CSS files that get pulled into our pages. Obviously, as one long string, it's hard to read. I'm wondering how I can target each URL path and manipulate it in order to much easily see which CSS files are being included on a page? The end result being the an extension which creates a new tab in Dev Tools and shows each CSS file on its own line.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or Sass?

Comment: It's a filepath of CSS and Sass files and you would manipulate the string via JS. So anyone with interest in these two things might be able to help.

Comment: But being an expert on CSS or Sass will not help you solve your problem.  Do not use tags unless your goal is to attract experts in those areas.

Comment: You can just use the Network Panel and apply "CSS" filter to show style requests only. If you happen to load CSS via XHR and append it to page via <style> tag, you can apply "XHR" filter and then search for ".css" in the file names.

Answer (score 0):

> The end result being the extension creates a new tab in dev tools and shows each css file on its own line.

Here is a bookmarklet which does the above:

```
javascript:void( function print_css_files() { 'use strict'; print_css_files.arr = []; for (var i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) { if(document.styleSheets[i].href) { print_css_files.arr.push(document.styleSheets[i].href); } } return alert(print_css_files.arr.join().replace(/\,/g,"\n\n") );}() );
```

which can be run on the console as such:

```
void
  (
  function print_css_files() 
    {
    'use strict';
    print_css_files.arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) 
        {
        if (document.styleSheets[i].href) 
            {
            print_css_files.arr.push(document.styleSheets[i].href);
            }
        }
    return alert(print_css_files.arr.join().replace(/\,/g, "\n\n"));
    }()
   )
```

or as a userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Print CSS Files
// @namespace    urn:print_css_files
// @version      0.1
// @description  Print CSS Files
// @author       upupdowndownleftrightleftrightbabastart
// @match        *
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
void
  (
  function print_css_files() 
    {
    'use strict';
    print_css_files.arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) 
        {
        if (document.styleSheets[i].href) 
            {
            print_css_files.arr.push(document.styleSheets[i].href);
            }
        }
    return alert(print_css_files.arr.join().replace(/\,/g, "\n\n"));
    }()
   )
```

**References**

- [Chromium: User Scripts](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts)
- [Chromium: Blink-in-JavaScript](https://www.chromium.org/blink/blink-in-js)